# How to retrieve the text of a DOM Text node?

Tags: javascript, dom

For a given Text node in the DOM, one can use one of these properties to retrieve its text:

- `textContent`
- `data`
- `nodeValue`
- `wholeText`

But which one to use? Which one is the most reliable and cross-browser supported?

(If multiple properties are 100% reliable and cross-browser, then which one would be most appropriate?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`nodeValue` <del>should be</del> is cross-browser compatible. [It is part of the original DOM Level 2 specification.](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68D080)

Also have a look at the [compatibility  table of  quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t22) for that matter (that's what I always use to see which properties are supported by which browsers).

Comment: If you look at that quirksmode sheet, you'll notice that `nodeValue` is "incomplete" in IE 5.5 whereas `data` is fully supported in that browser. It couldn't be less relevant, but still... `:)`

Comment: `data` is part of the DOM Level 2 spec as well, under the `CharacterData` interface. *No DOM objects correspond directly to CharacterData, though Text and others do inherit the interface from it.* (via: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-FF21A306)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Yes, but if you look at the note, then you will see that `nodeValue` just does not work with *attribute nodes* in IE 5.5, so it's fine for text nodes. I didn't know about `data`, to be honest ;)

Comment: I've used `data` for years, and it's rock solid in all major browsers.

Comment: So many properties and methods are named `data` these days that having that in there tells you nothing about what the code is doing. Its meaning is not obvious. `innerText` and `textContent` (or even jquery.text()) make it immediately obvious what you're trying to do.

Comment: @mastaBlasta But be aware that `nodeValue` will also return content for `attribute` nodes, but the `data` will return undefined for non text nodes (and comments), and this is most probably what we want from simple text nodes. see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12287159/2803565

Answer (score -1):

When you're 100% sure that it's a text node you can use any of them.

Comment: That is not true. `textContent` was only introduced in IE 9.

Comment: @AronWoost My idea is that one of them is most appropriate,and I want to be using that one.