# When working with text nodes should I use the "data", "nodeValue", "textContent" or "wholeText" field?

Tags: html, dom, cross-browser, textnode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to retrieve the text of a DOM Text node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690627/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-dom-text-node)

In my experiments to handle DOM mutation observers I've noticed that when the `target` is a text node there are four fields all containing the new text of the node.

- `data`
- `nodeValue`
- `textContent`
- `wholeText`

Is there a "best practice" for which of these fields I should use?

Are some just for compatibility with other browsers or older DOM standards? Does it make a difference whether I'm reading vs modifying the text? If one is best what is the purpose of the others?

Comment: This question is closed incorrectly. The answer to this question is much better than for the "duplicate", has much more upvotes and **explains the exact difference between the properties**.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Of all these I'd choose `data`: it is defined for the nodes implementing [**CharacterData**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-FF21A306) interface ([**Text**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772) and [**Comment**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1728279322) ones) only. Trying to access this property for the others gives `undefined`.

[nodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeValue) is essentially the same as `data` for text nodes, but is actually defined for attribute and comment nodes as well. And I usually want my programs to fail early. )

[textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) is, for me, something completely different, as it represents the text content of a node *and its descendants*. This, along with [wholeText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Text.wholeText), perhaps should be used more to collect texts from more complex structures than a single text node.

Said all that, `textContent` and `wholeText` were defined in DOM Level 3 (= more modern).

Comment: I actually used `data` too before I asked here. I think partly because it was first alphabetically and partly because it was the most concise. Good to have more deterministic reasons though! (-:

Comment: Actually it appears that of these four, only textContent is writeable... (or rather, it's the only one that seems to update that actual displayed content). why is this?

Comment: Correction: `data` is not defined "for text nodes only", but for the [CharacterData interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-FF21A306), which is not only inherit by [Text nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772), but also [Comment nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1728279322).