# Add html element values to javascript object properties

Tags: javascript, html, object

I have a javascript object and an html table.

```js
     var myObj = [
 {
           price: 1,
           label: "One"
        }
     ];
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id = "price">100</th>
    <th id = "label">product</th>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Is it possible to insert the table values in the object?

In order to have updated properties

```
{
price: 100,
label: "product"
}
```

Comment: Just a comment about your use of "id". Ids are unique. You should not use them if you intend to manage several rows. Is it so ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean

```
myObj.price=parseInt(document.getElementById("price").innerHTML,10);
```

for integers or

```
myObj.price=parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").innerHTML);
```

if price has decimals

and for the label:

```
myObj.label=document.getElementById("label").innerHTML;
```

Please note that `.innerHTML` is compatible with older browsers - if you do not need to support them, use `.textContent` instead

Like

```js
var myObj = [
 {
           price: 1,
           label: "One"
        }
     ];
window.onload=function() {
  myObj.price=parseInt(document.getElementById("price").innerHTML,10);
  myObj.label=document.getElementById("label").innerHTML; 
  window.console&&console.log(myObj)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id = "price">100</th>
    <th id = "label">product</th>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering this code :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id = "price">100</th>
    <th id = "label">product</th>
  </tr>
<table>
```

To get these values :

```
document.getElementById("price").nodeValue;
document.getElementById("label").nodeValue;
```

See Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cvu1h6wa/).

Then to convert the amount as integer, use `parseInt(string)`. As float values (it's an amount), use `parseFloat(string)`.

Instead of `nodeValue` you can use `textContent`, `data` or `wholeText`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286975/when-working-with-text-nodes-should-i-use-the-data-nodevalue-textcontent) to know more and to fit your needs.